# Square layout on GridLayoutManager for RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I try to make a grid-layout with square images. I thought that it must be possible to manipulate the `GridLayoutManager` by manipulating `onMeasure` to do a

```
super.onMeasure(recycler, state, widthSpec, widthSpec);
```

instead of

```
super.onMeasure(recycler, state, widthSpec, heightSpec);
```

but unfortunately, that didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: you were right with overriding onMeasure, but not in LayoutManager, do it in the View created in the adapter in onCreateViewHolder

Answer (score 157, accepted):

To have the square elements in my RecyclerView, I provide a simple wrapper for my root View element; I use the following `SquareRelativeLayout` in place of `RelativeLayout`.

```
package net.simplyadvanced.widget;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

/** A RelativeLayout that will always be square -- same width and height,
 * where the height is based off the width. */
public class SquareRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {

    public SquareRelativeLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public SquareRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,         int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // Set a square layout.
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    }

}
```

Then, in my XML layout for the adapter, I've just referenced the custom view as shown in the following. Though, you can do this programmatically also.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<net.simplyadvanced.widget.SquareRelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/elementRootView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!-- More widgets here. -->

</net.simplyadvanced.widget.SquareRelativeLayout>
```

Note: Depending on which orientation your grid is, then you may want to have the width based off of height (`GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL`) instead of the height being based off the width (`GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL`).

Comment: awesome job, quick note though, there is no need to your footnote, since GridLayoutManager takes care of it

Comment: Why do you use RelativeLayout? Wouldn't LinearLayout make more sense?

Comment: You should be able to use any root view that you want. The key is to override the `onMeasure(...)`

Comment: Work with Glide perfactly.

Comment: If you need a full visible square in landscape mode, you can do that by getting the minimum value (from width and height) and set that value to both sizes. Example: onMeasure(...) { int size = Math.min(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec); super.onMeasure(size, size); }

Comment: The constructor targeting the lollipop api did not work for me. It couldn't find the constructor.

Answer (score 122):

Constraint layout solves this problem. Use `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"`

***recyclerview_grid_layout.xml***

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**EDIT**

Set ImageView width to `0dp`. `match_parent` is now deprecated for ConstraintLayout.

Comment: @andryr I agree with you. I had to set mine to 0dp width also. Probably its due to some recent updates with constraint layout.

Comment: Works with `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="W, 1:1"`

Answer (score 20):

In case someone would like to scale the view differently - this is how you do it:

```
private static final double WIDTH_RATIO = 3;
private static final double HEIGHT_RATIO = 4;
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int heightSize = (int) (HEIGHT_RATIO / WIDTH_RATIO * widthSize);
    int newHeightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(heightSize, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, newHeightSpec);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this additional bit of info. Multiplying the widthMeasureSpec by the desired aspect ratio seemed logical, but obviously did not work.

Answer (score 9):

Starting API 26 (Support Library 26.0), one can use ConstraintLayout that exposes aspect ratio property to force views to be squared:
https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.htm

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    ...
}
...
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta1' //use whatever version is current
}
```

Example of layout I'm using in GridLayoutManager:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_small"
    android:background="@drawable/border_gray"
    android:gravity="center">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <!-- place your content here -->


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

`app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h,1:1"` is the key attribute here

Answer (score 8):

A small update for ConstraintLayout for androidx.

Include this line to your build.gradle:

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2'
```

I wanted to get a RecycleView with GridLayoutManager with square CardViews and I used such a layout for items:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp"
    >

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        >
```

On the ConstraintLayout

- layout_width="**match_parent**" is important to let the item fill as much space as RecyclerView provides
- layout_height="**wrap_content**" do not let the item to fill all the height given by RecyclerView, but use the constrained height, provided by ConstraintLayout. In my case, when I used FrameLayout or LinearLayout, the items were "tall".

On the child node, in my case CardView

- limiting size to zero is important: layout_width="0dp" and layout_height="0dp" it means, that width and height are contrained
- **layout_constraintDimensionRatio**="H,1:1" makes the desired effect, by setting H you define that height is to be constrained 1:1 is the ratio.

See some detailed explanations on the [offsite](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout.html#DimensionConstraints).

Answer (score 3):

Please, try this extension of the FrameLayout. It performs double measuring to improve consistency. It also supports custom XML properties to set-up required aspect ration from layouts

```
public class StableAspectFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {

    private int aspectWidth = 1;
    private int aspectHeight = 1;

    public StableAspectFrameLayout(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public StableAspectFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public StableAspectFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        extractCustomAttrs(context, attrs);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public StableAspectFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        extractCustomAttrs(context, attrs);
    }

    private void extractCustomAttrs(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        if (attrs == null) return;
        TypedArray a = context.getResources().obtainAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.StableAspectFrameLayout);
        try {
            aspectWidth = a.getInteger(R.styleable.StableAspectFrameLayout_aspect_width, 1);
            aspectHeight = a.getInteger(R.styleable.StableAspectFrameLayout_aspect_height, 1);
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int newSpecWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getMeasuredWidth(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        int newH = Math.round(((float) getMeasuredWidth()) * aspectHeight / aspectWidth);
        int newSpecHeigh = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(newH, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        super.onMeasure(newSpecWidth, newSpecHeigh);
    }
}
```

And the content fo the **attrs.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!--  StableAspectFrameLayout  -->
    <declare-styleable name="StableAspectFrameLayout">
        <attr name="aspect_width" format="integer"/>
        <attr name="aspect_height" format="integer"/>
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

Once again, I recommend the relatively recent 'percent' layouts. Using the dependency `'com.android.support:percent:25.2.0'`, you can do something like this:

```
<android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/image"
         app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
         app:layout_aspectRatio="100%"
         android:padding="10dp"
         android:scaleType="centerCrop"
         android:cropToPadding="true"
         tools:background="#efdbed"
         />
   </android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout>
```

It's probably much faster than ConstraintLayout, though someday we probably won't care anymore.

Comment: As of release 26.0.0, the Percent Support library is deprecated. Clients of this module should migrate to the new ConstraintLayout widget, which is provided as a separate artifact in SDK Manager.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like chosen answer so let me provide mine: Instead of wrapping entire item layout in SomeDammyLayoutWithFixedAspectRatio you can hack GridLayoutManager and rewrite code inside measureChild. I've replaced these lines:

```
if (mOrientation == VERTICAL) {
        wSpec = getChildMeasureSpec(availableSpaceInOther, otherDirParentSpecMode,
                horizontalInsets, lp.width, false);
        hSpec = getChildMeasureSpec(mOrientationHelper.getTotalSpace(), getHeightMode(),
                verticalInsets, lp.height, true);
    } else {
        hSpec = getChildMeasureSpec(availableSpaceInOther, otherDirParentSpecMode,
                verticalInsets, lp.height, false);
        wSpec = getChildMeasureSpec(mOrientationHelper.getTotalSpace(), getWidthMode(),
                horizontalInsets, lp.width, true);
    }
```

to:

```
if (mOrientation == VERTICAL) {
        wSpec = getChildMeasureSpec(availableSpaceInOther, otherDirParentSpecMode,
                horizontalInsets, lp.width, false);
        hSpec = wSpec;
    } else {
        hSpec = getChildMeasureSpec(availableSpaceInOther, otherDirParentSpecMode,
                verticalInsets, lp.height, false);
        wSpec = hSpec;
    }
```

It seems to work fine.

Don't get me wrong, this is quite messy too, but at least this solution doesn't hurt app performance by extending view hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and I had to inflate the view which would be square in Grid of recycler view. Below is my way of doing it.

Inside onCreateViewHolder method I used the ViewTreeObserver and GlobalLayoutListener to get the measured width of the layout. The layout has match_parent value in the width attribute. Any my recycler view has layout in center horizontal.

```
final View view = LayoutInflater.from(mActivity).inflate(R.layout.list_item_deals, parent, false);
    view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            int side = view.getMeasuredWidth();

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = view.getLayoutParams();
            lp.width = side;
            lp.height = side;
            view.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }
    });
```

[reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1uzB.png)