# Set ImageView's width to fill white space (keeping aspect ratio) inside RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I have `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManger`

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.movie_posters_recycler_view);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2));
```

Each RecyclerView's item represented by following layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/movie_item_poster_image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Currently I have such result

[image: layout1]

I want to do this

[image: layout2]

Answer (score 4):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/movie_thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

Replace your image view with this one

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/movie_item_poster_image_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```

Comment: It doesn't keep aspect ratio

Comment: images your getting are smaller buddy if you want a layout like that manually set height and width of your `ImageView` in dp

Comment: Yes, but for example 200dp width is good for 7" tablet and bad for 9" one and so on. Thats the problem. I wanted to find out solution to stretch images automatically depending on free space on the screen.

Comment: so include different xml for different screens like , 1 for 7 inch and 1 for 10 inch and i for phones, you can put them in different folders in res folder but make sure to keep the name of the xml same and android will automatically use the one with respect to device.

Answer (score 0):

please add to scaltype to image view in your adapter to fitxy

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26575808/4729523.

You just need to keep the image's aspect ratio (3/4 or 9/16).

Answer (score 0):

Using `android:scaleType="fitXY"` in `ImageView` attributes should stretch the image inside the `ImageView`.