# Align Buttons as a Grid Layout in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I am making an app with Android Studio and want to display buttons side by side with three columns per row. I managed to achieve this on the first row but the second row is all messed up.. this is what I am looking for:

[image]

this is what I have tried:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollablContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/englishstatus"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:text="Download Code"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/linestatus"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/englishstatus"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:text="Download Code"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/bg" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/attitude"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:text="Download Code"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg" />
```

i am getting this as output[image]

Comment: You should use `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager`

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587168/simple-android-grid-example-using-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager-like-the

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve your requirement

> First using Linear layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

> Second way

You can use `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager`

```
GridLayoutManager  gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(YourActivity.this, 3);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
```

Check out this article for [`RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40587168/7666442)

> Third way you can use  a [`GridView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView)

Check out this article for [Android Grid View](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_grid_view.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Recyclerview with SquareRelativeLayout as item, please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566954/square-layout-on-gridlayoutmanager-for-recyclerview/26575808)

Answer (score 0):

You can use TableLayout and you can add buttons to rows and columns. Check this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout).

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, you'd better provide complete layout code.

btw, it's better to use RecyclerView and GridLayoutManager in this situation.